# What configuration am I doing wrong in Laravel 8 Cors?

Tags: laravel, cors

I am working with an API in Laravel 8, everything works perfect except for a problem that I am having with the Cors file.

What I want to do is that the GETs of an API can only be consulted from [www.exampledomain.com](http://www.exampledomain.com)
In the cors.php file I have the following configuration:

```
'paths' => ['api / *', 'sanctum / csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['www.exampledomain.com'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

However it allows me to make GET requests from another domain.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

I understand that this used to be done with Middlewares, but according to the official [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#cors) that no longer needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php artisan config:clear
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Or

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and I have not had a successful result.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue right now, something is missing or not clear for me with cors config on laravel, all requests passes without restriction although I restricted access in the config.